# Custom content type with field that creates its own CSS?

Tags: drupal

I'm looking to create a content type which includes a field for an image file - simple enough. However, I want this image file to be displayed as a background-image. Do I have to create a custom node.tpl and include the image source in an inline `style="background: url(sites/all/themes/theme/images/image.png);"`, or is there a more elegant way to do this, possibly including writing to a stylesheet from the field using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use drupal_add_css in a hook_node_view function, node preprocess script, or node template to add a style directly:

```
$css = "#bg-img { 
  background: url(/sites/all/themes/theme/images/image.png) left top no-repeat; 
};"
drupal_add_css($css, 'inline');
```

Or, you can use a drupal setting and then reference it in a jquery script; look up [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) usage & examples with the 'setting' option:

```
drupal_add_js(array("moduleName" => array('bgImg' => $absolute_url)), 'setting');
```

Reference in jQuery using Drupal.settings.moduleName['bgImg']

IMO adjusting the node.tpl.php as you describe is perfectly sensible. Using drupal_add_css  will let you set a background image on an element outside the node, eg the entire page. I've used jquery when I've needed more advanced positioning/resizing options.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Didn't know about drupal_add_css, looks useful.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading documentations and digging into codes, just use Field Formatter CSS module (https://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class) and get it done in minutes.  It's a gem that you will find yourself using it over and over.  It lets you add css classes and other options to each field in the "Manage display" of your custom content type.  As for this particular case of serving a user-uploaded image as background, here is a screen capture.  Add a class into the Field Formatter Class field, and then you should be able to reposition and resize further with css and jquery.

[image]